# Right way for canonicals with Laravel , Duplicate meta descriptions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, seo, meta-tags, meta

i'm using laravel 5 for my news project.

I have Duplicate meta descriptions ( 1320 error ).  i tried to solve it with canonicals but no way.

my errors like :

```
https:///blog/this-is-a-blog-topic
/blog/this-is-a-blog-topic
```

so this means i have same thing with different urls , 
my canonical section in head tags like this :

```
@if( request()->url() == url('/') )
     <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.mynewswebsite.com/" />
@else
     <link rel="canonical" href="{!! request()->fullUrl() !!}"  />
@endif
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725158/laravel-5-2-metatag-canonical-url