# How to Canonicalise paginated 1st page to original page

Tags: php, html, laravel, meta

I have added the canonical tag in my every page like

in my app.blade.php

```
<link rel='conanical' href="@yeild('conanical-tags')">
```

in my other pages

```
@section('conanical-tags')
{{ url()->current() }}
@endsection
```

But I want to conanicalise the first paginated urls like 
if

```
www.example.com/something?page=1
```

I want to conanicalise it to

```
www.example.com/something
```

How to do this ?

Comment: is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725158/laravel-5-2-metatag-canonical-url